# How to obtain a specific value from TreeView Widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to obtain a specific value from the datastructure produced form my treeview.

Here is the treeview being defined.

```
ScoutCalenderView= ttk.Treeview(ScoutCalendar)
ScoutCalenderView["columns"] = ("eventname","startdate","enddate","starttime","endtime","cost","limits")
ScoutCalenderView.grid(row=1,column=1)
ScoutCalenderView.heading("#0", text="",anchor="w")
ScoutCalenderView.column("#0",anchor="center",width=5,stretch=tk.NO)
ScoutCalenderView.heading("eventname", text="Event Name",anchor="w")
ScoutCalenderView.column("eventname",anchor="center",width=80)
ScoutCalenderView.heading("startdate", text="Start Date",anchor="w")
ScoutCalenderView.column("startdate",anchor="center",width=70)
ScoutCalenderView.heading("enddate", text="End Date",anchor="w")
ScoutCalenderView.column("enddate",anchor="center",width=70)
ScoutCalenderView.heading("starttime", text="Start Time",anchor="w")
ScoutCalenderView.column("starttime",anchor="center",width=70)
ScoutCalenderView.heading("endtime", text="End Time",anchor="w")
ScoutCalenderView.column("endtime",anchor="center",width=70)
ScoutCalenderView.heading("cost", text="Cost",anchor="w")
ScoutCalenderView.column("cost",anchor="center",width=70)
ScoutCalenderView.heading("limits", text="Limit",anchor="w")
ScoutCalenderView.column("limits",anchor="center",width=70)
ScoutCalenderView.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', selectItem)
ScoutCalenderView.grid(row=3,column=1,columnspan=5)
```

This is the function called when the Button is released.

```
    def selectItem(a):
curItem = ScoutCalenderView.focus()
print(ScoutCalenderView.item(curItem))
```

The line print(ScoutCalenderView.item(curItem)) yields, for example:

```
{'text': '', 'image': '', 'values': ['jhgfds', '16/11/2018', '16/11/2018', '14:35', '14:35', '£0.0', 0], 'open': 0, 'tags': ''}
```

As you can see, there is only data in the values part of the dictionary. I would like to be able to obtain the values in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply extract the "values" from the dictionary. It will give you already a list:

```
inter_var=ScoutCalenderView.item(curItem)
list_values=inter_var['values']
```

If you print `list_values`, you will obtain in this case:

```
['jhgfds', '16/11/2018', '16/11/2018', '14:35', '14:35', '£0.0', 0]
```